# c# Creating an unknown generic type at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

So I have a class that is a generic and it may need to, inside a method of its own, create an instance of itself with a different kind of generic, whose type is obtained through reflection.

This is important because this Repository maps `T` to a database table [it's an ORMish I am writing] and if the class that represents `T` has a collection representing ANOTHER table I need to be able to instance that and pass it to the repository [ala Inception].
I'm providing the method in case it makes it easier to see the problem.

```
private PropertiesAttributesAndRelatedClasses GetPropertyAndAttributesCollection() 
{
  // Returns a List of PropertyAndAttributes

  var type = typeof(T);
  //For type T return an array of PropertyInfo

  PropertiesAttributesAndRelatedClasses PAA = new PropertiesAttributesAndRelatedClasses();
  //Get our container ready

  //Let's loop through all the properties.
  PropertyAndAttributes _paa;
  foreach(PropertyInfo Property in type.GetProperties())
  {
    //Create a new instance each time.
    _paa = new PropertyAndAttributes();

    //Adds the property and generates an internal collection of attributes for it too
    _paa.AddProperty(Property);

    bool MapPropertyAndAttribute = true;
    //This is a class we need to map to another table
    if (Property.PropertyType.Namespace == "System.Collections.Generic")
    {
      PAA.AddRelatedClass(Property);
      //var x = Activator.CreateInstance("GenericRepository", Property.GetType().ToString());
    }
    else 
    {
      foreach(var attr in _paa.Attrs) 
      {
        if (attr is IgnoreProperty)
        {
          //If we find this attribute it is an override and we ignore this property.
          MapPropertyAndAttribute = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    //Add this to the list.
    if (MapPropertyAndAttribute) PAA.AddPaa(_paa);
  }
  return PAA;
}
```

So given
`GenericRepository<T>`, and I want to make a `GenericRepository<string type obtained via reflection from the Property>` how would I do this?
The line I need to replace with something that WORKS is:

```
//var x = Activator.CreateInstance("GenericRepository", Property.GetType().ToString());
```

Thanks.

Comment: How is the property (the one of type `System.Collections.Generic`) declared in your C# code? Is its type argument `<T>` the same as that of the `GenericRepository<T>` that owns the property?

Comment: No, basically it is just a generic collection of another class as a property on a class.
i.e. A Teacher class has a list of classes class.
The repository gets the teacher class and has to also process the classes class, but since it is really getting T it has to figure out what it has to process using reflection

Comment: So is the property in the `Teacher` class declared as `List<Class> Classes {/*getter and/or setter*/}`? Wouldn't `Activator.CreateInstance(Property.GetType())` work then?

Comment: ah but I need a REPOSITORY [my own generic] of type T where T = Classes if the currently instanced repository is T = Teachers.  What you suggest would work but just to create the type Classes

Comment: Both answers below are correct then. Did they work for you?

Comment: Yes tested and both work.  I +1 both but gave the best answer to the one that was easier to understand.  Thank you both.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) method:

```
// Assuming that Property.PropertyType is something like List<T>
Type elementType = Property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
Type repositoryType = typeof(GenericRepository<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
var repository = Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType);
```

Comment: If I may, I am running into 1 problem.  I cannot access any methods for the given repository.
If I access it via the immediate window where it made say GenericRepository<Locations> and I do
?((GenericRepository<DocerZocer.Models.Location>)repository).GetAll()
This properly works, how can I cast it properly in the code such that I don't need this? Obviously I can only do it in the immediate window because I know the type it represents.

Comment: @Jordan, you could create a non-generic `IRepository` interface with a `GetAll` method that returns an array of objects, and implement this interface explicitly in the `GenericRepository<T>` class. Or you could call the method dynamically using reflection, but it's slower...

Answer (score 4):

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(GenericRepository<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { Property.GetTYpe() }))
```

Comment: This will create an instance of `GenericRepository<RuntimePropertyInfo>`, since `Property.GetType()` returns `RuntimePropertyInfo`...