# C# Pass Dictionary of Class Types Into Generic

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I have a dictionary of class types that looks like this:

```
    private static Dictionary<int, Type> GetArrayOfClassInstances()
    {
        var availability = new LeisureLinkBaseProduct.Availability();
        var baseRate = new LeisureLinkBaseProduct.BaseRate();
        var stayRestrictions = new LeisureLinkBaseProduct.StayRestrictions();
        var checkInInformation = new LeisureLinkBaseProduct.CheckInInformation();
        var specials = new LeisureLinkBaseProduct.Specials();
        var taxes = new LeisureLinkBaseProduct.Taxes();
        var fees = new LeisureLinkBaseProduct.Fees();

        var classDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Type>();
        classDictionary.Add(1, availability.GetType());
        classDictionary.Add(2, baseRate.GetType());
        classDictionary.Add(3, stayRestrictions.GetType());
        classDictionary.Add(4, checkInInformation.GetType());
        classDictionary.Add(5, specials.GetType());
        classDictionary.Add(6, taxes.GetType());
        classDictionary.Add(7, fees.GetType());

        return classDictionary;
    }
```

And I want to pass it into this generic method that looks like this:

```
                var classes = GetArrayOfClassInstances();

                foreach (var instance in classes)
                {
                    var request = RequestBuilder.BuildAdditionalDataRequest(link.href);
                    var response = Api<instance.value>(request.Endpoint);
                }
```

but I get the intellisense error "instance is a variable but is used like a type" how do I pass this class type into the generic then? Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: As a total aside to your question, you dont need to create an instance to get its type, you can do (for example) `var taxes = typeof(LeisureLinkBaseProduct.Taxes);`

Comment: o nice that's way better then what I was doing

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class?rq=1) talks about instantiating a generic class with a `Type` instance, but the process will be similar if `Api` in your code is a method call.

Comment: If you use @Jamiec's answer then you end up with an `object` back. If you must cast this object to a type anyway then you haven't gained anything with that answer; instead of `switch`'ing over generic `Api<generic>` method calls you are `switch`'ing over a bunch of returned `object`'s to cast them.

Comment: Exactly, I was skirting over the point that generics are great when you know the type at compile time and near-on useless if you dont (for the reason @Quantic mentions)

Comment: right got that, do you have to pass the literal class type into the generic though?

Comment: @AdamWeitzman yes - you would do `Api<LeisureLinkBaseProduct.Taxes>(...)`

Comment: @AdamWeitzman: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: yes sorry your answer worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following ran for me and is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965893/c-sharp-creating-an-unknown-generic-type-at-runtime):

**Api Class:**

```
public class Api<T>
{
    public Api(Type E){}
}
```

**Create Api Method:**

```
    private static void CreateApis()
    {
        var classes = GetArrayOfClassInstances();


        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Type> instance in classes)
        {
            Type apiType = typeof(Api<>).MakeGenericType(instance.Value);

            var api = Activator.CreateInstance(apiType, new[]{typeof(System.Net.EndPoint)});
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need reflection as the type is not known at compile-time:

```
typeof(Api<>).MakeGenericType(instance.value)
    .GetConstructor(new[] {typeof(Endpoint)})
    .Invoke(new[]{request.Endpoint});
```

Comment: intellisense blows up on this one, maybe im using it wrong?

Comment: i need to look into reflection a bit more, its quite over my head at the moment