# Get list of type(s) of specific interface implemented by concrete class

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Given a class, how can i find the types for the INotificationHandler<>:

```
public class OtherClass : INotificationHandler<Aggregate>, INotificationHandler<Quote>
{
  /* */
}

var typesList = [] { typeof(OtherClass) };

var result = MagicFunctionToGetTemplateTypesForNotificationHandlerInterface(typesList)

// where result = [] { typeof(Aggregate), typeof(Quote) };
```

I am considering going down the road of `GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0]` however want to check if there is a safer way first.

I have tried searching and appreciate this could very well be a duplicate, if so please let me know and I will delete.

Comment: Yes, it likely looks as duplicate with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965893/c-sharp-creating-an-unknown-generic-type-at-runtime) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class) as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var result = typeof(OtherClass).GetInterfaces()
    .Where(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(INotificationHandler<>))
    .Select(x => x.GetGenericArguments()[0])
    .ToArray();
```