# C# dynamic list of classes using interface

Tags: c#

I need to create an interface where all inherited classes must also provide their own object type to be used. I started out like this:

```
public interface ICompositeComponent
{
    string UIName { get; set; }
    object DataModel { get; set; }
}
```

This does not work for the inherited classes as I cannot specific any other type for the DataModel property. I then learned to do it this way:

```
public interface ICompositeComponent<T>
{
    string UIName { get; set; }
    T DataModel { get; set; }
}
```

This solves my problem very well. Now I can do this:

```
public class ImageWrapper : ICompositeComponent<Image>
{
    public string UIName { get; set; } = "UIImage";
    public Image DataModel  { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have a class that contains a list of these components, I'd like to do something like this:

```
public List<ICompositeComponent<T>> Components { get; set; } = new List<ICompositeComponent<T>>();
```

Of course, this does not work. Just how do I create a list of components? Basically, what I am trying to achieve is to have a list of "dynamic" classes (each is different) but share some common properties (like the UIName I have in the sample). Then I will add such component one by one into the list and let the parent class loop through them and render them as UI.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: When you say "Of course, this does not work.", what do you mean? What error are you getting?

Comment: If you want a polymorphic list that can store an arbitrary component type for each list item, it will have to be instantiated using `List<ICompositeComponent<dynamic>>` or `List<ICompositeComponent<object>>`, or even just `List<ICompositeComponent>` storing an object or dynamic. When you retrieve the component, you can cast it back to the type you want, assuming you also keep track of the type you stored in `ICompositeComponent`.

Comment: If the list will contain the same type for each item, you can specialize it to that type with `new List<ICompositeComponent<MyType>>();`

Comment: ESG, the error was the type or namespace name 'T" could not be found. @Robert, if it's dynamic, how do I cast them to their corresponding object type? I need to be able to call the DataModel property of each object. I cannot use a specific concrete type, that's why I am using interface.

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4925718/102937).

Comment: Unfortunately, I suspect you're trying to data-bind these things, which isn't going to work with dynamic types.   Is this some sort of plug-in architecture you're creating?

Comment: You should also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8965893/102937).

Comment: For you "dynamic" object, can you create a base interface with shared properties? Then use ```List<ICompositeComponent<IBaseData>> Components {get;set;}```? Where interface ```IBaseData``` contains all shared properties.

Comment: @Jivopis that's a very interesting idea! gonna give it a try, thanks!